# Get only rows where exists in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, exists

I need to select all rows from table: `Announcements` where there are exist rows in table `Categories_announcements` for user by condition:

`Categories_user.category_id = Categories_announcements.category_id`

I tried SQL query, see [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec162/3/0)

It should returns me onlu one row `Announcements.id = 1`, because user has only one category in `Categories_user.category_id`.

#### EDIT:

I have tested SQL that you shared, so this is query:

```
select *
from `announcements`
where exists (
        select 1
        from `announcement_category`
        inner join `user_category` on `user_category`.`category_id` = `announcement_category`.`category_id`
        where `Auser_category`.`user_id` = 1
            and `announcement_category`.`announcement_id` = announcements.id
        )
```

It returns me an error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7`

Comment: Using SQLFiddle is fine. But you should also add the query to you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correlate the subquery with the Announcements table:

```
select *
from Announcements a
where exists (
        select 1
        from Categories_announcements ca
        inner join Categories_user cu on cu.category_id = ca.category_id
        where cu.user_id = 1
            and ca.announcement_id = a.id
        )
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec162/5)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need an EXISTS subquery. A basic join statement should work.

```
select a.* 
from Categories_user cu
join Categories_announcements ca on ca.category_id = cu.category_id
join Announcements a on a.id = ca.announcement_id
where cu.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Can you help me write this query in Laravel  eloquent?

Comment: @Darama If you want an eloquent solution you would need to define the models and relations first. But i wouldn't change this question too much, because you've already got a lot of answers. Write a new question tagged with laravel. After defining the relations the answer might be as simple as `$user->announcements;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  Try this:

```
select a.*
from Announcements a
where exists (select 1
              from Categories_announcements ca join
                   Categories_user cu
                   on cu.category_id = ca.category_id 
              where ca.announcement_id = a.id and
                    cu.user_id = 1
             );
```

Notes:

- The key thing you are missing is the correlation clause to the outer query (`ca.announcement_id = a.id`).
- The `left join` is superfluous.  The `where` clause turns it into an inner join.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

You'r query is missing a relationship between the `announcement` table in the outer query to the condition in the inner one:

```
SELECT *
FROM   announcements a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT    * 
               FROM      categories_announcements ca
               LEFT JOIN categories_user cu ON cu.category_id = ca.category_id 
               WHERE     cu.user_id = 1 AND
                         a.id = ca.announcement_id -- Here!
              )
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec162/7/0)

Comment: What about perfomance? is it speed request for 1000 announcements?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround without a sub-query:

```
SELECT a.id AS accouncement_id, a.name AS annoucement_name 
FROM Categories_user cu
INNER JOIN Categories_announcements ca 
        ON  cu.category_id = ca.category_id
        AND cu.user_id = 1
INNER JOIN Announcements a 
        ON ca.announcement_id = a.id;
```

[Demo link](http://rextester.com/DIF6766)